# Socket using BufferedOutputStream/BufferedInputStream receives bogus data random

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream

I have a client/server application that sends/receives data using `BufferedOutputStream / BufferedInputStream` . The protocol of communication is the following:

1. Send part :

   - first byte is the action to perform
   - next 4 bytes are the length of the message
   - next x bytes (x=length of message) are the message itself
2. Receive part :

   - read first byte to get the action
   - read the next 4 bytes to get the message length
   - read the x (obtained on prev step) bytes to get the message

Now the problem is that **sometimes** when i sent the length of the message (ex : 23045) on server part when i receive it i get a huge int (ex: 123106847).

A important clue is that this happens **only** when message exceeds a number of characters  (in my case > 10K ) , if i sent a smaller message (ex 4-5k) everything works as expected.

Client send part (outputStream/inputStream are the type BufferedXXXStream):

```
    private String getResponseFromServer( NormalizerActionEnum action, String message) throws IOException{

        writeByte( action.id());
        writeString( message);
        flush(;

        return read();
    }

    private String read() throws IOException{
        byte[] msgLen = new byte[4];
        inputStream.read(msgLen);
        int len = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgLen).getInt();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
        inputStream.read(bytes);

        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private void writeByte( byte msg) throws IOException{
        outputStream.write(msg);
    }

    private void writeString( String msg) throws IOException{

        byte[] msgLen = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(msg.length()).array();

        outputStream.write(msgLen);
        outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    }

    private void flush() throws IOException{
        outputStream.flush();
    }
```

Server part (_input/_output are the type BufferedXXXStream)

```
private byte readByte() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int b =  _input.read();
    while(b==-1){
        Thread.sleep(1);
        b = _input.read();
    }

    return (byte) b;
}

private String readString() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    byte[] msgLen = new byte[4];
    int s = _input.read(msgLen);
    while(s==-1){
        Thread.sleep(1);
        s = _input.read(msgLen);
    }   

    int len = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgLen).getInt();     
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    s = _input.read(bytes);
    while(s==-1){
        Thread.sleep(1);
        s = _input.read(bytes);
    }

    return new String(bytes);
}

private void writeString(String message) throws IOException {
    byte[] msgLen = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(message.length()).array();
    _output.write(msgLen);
    _output.write(message.getBytes());
    _output.flush();
}

....

byte cmd = readByte();
String message = readString();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you need additional details let me know.

**UPDATE:** Due to comments from ***Jon Skeet*** and ***EJP*** i realized that the read part on the server was having some pointless operations but letting this aside i finally got what the problem was: the key thing is that i keep the streams opened for the full length of the app and the first several times i sent the message length i'm able to read it on the server side BUT as ***Jon Skeet*** pointed out the data doesn't arrive all at once so when i try to read the message length again i'm actually reading from the message itself that is why i have bogus message lengths .

~ instead of sending the data length and then reading it all at once i sent it without the length and i read one byte at a time till the end of the string which works perfectly

```
private String readString() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    int s = 0;
    int index=0;
    while(true){
        s = _input.read();
        if(s == 10){
            break;
        }
        bytes[index++] = (byte) (s);
        if(index == bytes.length){
            sb.append(new String(bytes));
            bytes = new byte[100];
            index=0;
        }           
    }
    if(index > 0){
        sb.append(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, index)));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The `sleep()` is pointless. `read()` already blocks until input is available. And sleeping and re-reading while the return value is -1 is even more pointless, as there will certainly never be anything more to read. Did you mean `while (s != -1)`?

Comment: @EJP Your right , I know that is pointless now but leaving that aside the main issue is that the length i sent i not the length i receive is some random cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
s = _input.read(bytes);
while(s==-1){
    Thread.sleep(1);
    s = _input.read(bytes);
}

return new String(bytes);
```

Firstly, the loop is pointless: the only time `read` will return -1 is if it's closed, in which case looping isn't going to help you.

Secondly, you're ignoring the possibility that the data will come in more than one chunk. You're assuming that if you've managed to get *any* data, you've got *all* the data. Instead, you should loop something like this:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead < bytes.length) {
    int chunk = _input.read(bytes, bytesRead, bytes.length - bytesRead);
    if (chunk == -1) {
        throw new IOException("Didn't get as much data as we should have");
    }
    bytesRead += chunk;
}
```

Note that all your *other* `InputStream.read` calls also assume that you've managed to read data, and indeed that you've read *all* the data you need.

Oh, and you're using the platform-default encoding to convert between binary data and text data - not a good idea.

Is there any reason you're not using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` for this? Currently you're reinventing the wheel, and doing so with bugs.

Comment: +1 thx for the input, you are right i was expecting to receive all the data at once since i flush it all , i wish i could apply you "chunk management" but the problem is at `len` : the length of the message which is bogus in same cases

Comment: regarding `DataInputStream` this was my first approach but the performance was slow comparing to the buffered approach

Comment: @Stephan: You can wrap a `BufferedInputStream` in a `DataInputStream` (and likewise for `DataOutputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`). Don't forget to flush though!

Comment: True , i thought of that but i was afraid of performance drop due to extra encapsulation but i will try

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i manage chunks if the length of the message is scrambled ?

Comment: @Stephan: What do you mean by "scrambled"?

Comment: for ex : on client i sent the message length [23045] but on server side when i read it i get big int like [123106847] that is why your approach from above will not work

Comment: I've updated the question (please review it when you have time) and thx to you i found a different approach that works but i'm still curious why the original problem occurred

Comment: I just tested you multi chunks scenario and you are 100 % right. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1):

You sending code is bugged:

```
byte[] msgLen = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(message.length()).array();
_output.write(msgLen);
_output.write(message.getBytes());
```

You send the number of *characters* as the message length, but after that you convert the message to bytes. Depending on the platform encoding String.getBytes() can give you much more bytes than there are characters.

You should *never* assume that String.length() has *any* relationship with String.getBytes().length! Those are different concepts and should never be mixed.

Comment: i thought of that as well but it not the case because : 1. its the same platform on both client and server 2. in same cases it works in other it doesn't

Comment: @Stephan Its not the platform that differs (although that a potential source of headache, too), its that String.length() and String.getBytes().length can give different values depending on *string contents* (to be clear: "a".length() == "a".getBytes("UTF-8").length *but* "\u20AC".length != "\u20AC".getBytes("UTF-8").length). Your code *is* bugged and thats why you get seemingly random results.

Comment: Fair enough ... i used `.getBytes().length` instead of `.length()` but the issue is the same

Comment: You reading methods has a similarly common mistake which Jon Skeet already pointed out: you don't ensure that you *really* have read the amount of bytes message length specifies. Jon Skeet also showed the code to ensure that the specified number of bytes is read (2nd code example). I presumed you already fixed that, but maybe it slipped by?

Comment: +1 for the valid points although the answer i was seeking, so i finally got what the problem was the key thing is that i keep the streams opened for the full length of the app and the first several times i sent the message length i'm able to read it on the server side BUT as Jon Skeet pointed out the data doesn't arrive all at once so when i try to read the message length again i'm actually reading from the message itself that is why i have bogus message lengths